# Ordering joined query by multiple rows of the joined table

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I've got a `posts` table and a `postmeta` table which contains `meta_key` and `meta_value` columns. I've included a simplified table structure below (with some demo data).

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `posts` (`id`, `title`) VALUES
    (1,'First post'),
    (2,'Second post'),
    (3,'Third post'),
    (4,'Fourth post');

CREATE TABLE `postmeta` (
  `meta_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `meta_key` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `meta_value` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`meta_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `postmeta` (`meta_id`, `post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES
    (1,1,'rating','80'),
    (2,1,'total_votes','500'),
    (3,2,'rating','80'),
    (4,2,'total_votes','501'),
    (5,3,'rating','95'),
    (6,3,'total_votes','200');
```

The posts need to be ordered by rating. Post without any rating need to be included too, hence the `LEFT JOIN`. No problem:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN postmeta m ON p.id = m.post_id AND m.meta_key = 'rating'
ORDER BY m.meta_value DESC
```

However, **for posts with the same rating, I'd like to further order them by the total vote count** which is stored in another row in the `postmeta` table. In the example above, the first and second post have a rating of 80 but since the second post has more votes, it should be ordered before the first post. How would you pull that off in a single query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * <-- you'll want to specify columns here
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN postmeta m ON p.id = m.post_id AND m.meta_key = 'rating'
LEFT JOIN postmeta mv ON p.id = mv.post_id AND mv.meta_key = 'total_votes'
ORDER BY m.meta_value DESC, mv.meta_value DESC
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ffabb/2)

**Output:**

```
| ID |       TITLE | META_ID | POST_ID | META_KEY | META_VALUE |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|  3 |  Third post |       5 |       3 |   rating |         95 |
|  2 | Second post |       3 |       2 |   rating |         80 |
|  1 |  First post |       1 |       1 |   rating |         80 |
|  4 | Fourth post |  (null) |  (null) |   (null) |     (null) |
```

Comment: Awesome! I'll bookmark that SQL Fiddle site too, will come in handy. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN postmeta m ON p.id = m.post_id AND m.meta_key = 'rating'
LEFT JOIN postmeta m2 ON p.id = m2.post_id AND m2.meta_key = 'total_votes'
ORDER BY m.meta_value DESC, m2.meta_value Desc
```